# Gather one field at a database call:: error php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
        <h2>User Profile: <?php if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);echo "&nbsp;{$row['uname']}";} else {echo "No data.";}?></h2>
        <span class="two">Registered Date: <?php if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);echo "&nbsp;{$row['regDate']}";} else {echo "No data.";}?> </span><br />
        <span class="three">Current Grade: <?php if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);echo "&nbsp;{$row['currGrade']}";} else {echo "No data.";}unset($sth);?> </span><br />
```

Error I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on line 30

Line 30 is:

```
    <span class="three">Current Grade: <?php if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);echo "&nbsp;{$row['currGrade']}";} else {echo "No data.";}unset($sth);?> </span><br />
```

SQL behind the scenes:

```
#Get Student Info :: for Page Content
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ureviewdu', $u, $p);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT uname, currGrade, regDate
    FROM Student
    WHERE usrID = ?;
    ;');
$sth->execute(array(
    $userID
));
```

This updated code yields nothing for each query... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unsetting the `PDOStatement` `$sth` variable at the end of each block. You won't be able to use it after unsetting it.

You should probably just create one logical branch based on the result of the fetch, eg

```
<?php if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
<h2>User Profile: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['uname']) ?></h2>
<span class="two">Registered Date: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['regDate']) ?></span><br />
<span class="three">Current Grade: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['currGrade']) ?></span><br />
<?php $sth->closeCursor(); else : ?>
<h2>User Profile: No data.</h2>
<span class="two">Registered Date: No Data.</span><br />
<span class="three">Current Grade: No Data.</span><br />
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: @user886187 I've updated my answer since you accepted it. Make sure it still applies

Comment: @user Your problem was a combination of unsetting the variable then attempting to use it again *and* attempting to fetch further rows from a single row result set. Notice I only call `$sth->fetch()` once. Each fetch loads the entire row into the `$row` variable

Answer (score 1):

I think every time you try to get a column value, actually you are also advancing a row in the resultset. `$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` assigns a row to `$row` AND advances the cursor.